# Jquery .show() not working with .find() on HTML5 data descriptor - help needed!

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mzhang23/CGfzq/9/

I am using the following code to try and allow a click on the blue shirt thumbnail image in the rightmost column to show the blue shirt image divs in the first and second column. (To test this, click the "x" on the blue shirt in the middle column to hide it first)

I've used an HTML 5 data-eltype descriptor for the third column image of the blue shirt and hope to use that descriptor to find the relevant class for the .show() function.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.thumbslist .element').click(function(){
        $('.outfit-box').find('.' + $(this).data('eltype')).show(250);
        });
        });    
    </script>
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery 1.4.2, what you want is to get the attribute data-eltype see: http://jsfiddle.net/CGfzq/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thumbslist .element').click(function(){
        $('.outfit-box').find('.' + $(this).attr('data-eltype')).show(250);
    });
});
```

**edit**

As @mu is too short points out, the method you tried will only work in more recent versions.

Comment: See my comment on Elon's answer about `.data`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

As mu pointed out, more recent versions of jQuery actually do utilize the .data() function to pull in HTML5 data- attributes. But I got lucky and escaped giving a wrong answer by the technicality that you happen to be using an older version of jQuery that does not support this... :-)

Original:

"data-eltype" is the name of the attribute, so to select it with jQuery you need to do this:

```
$(this).attr('data-eltype');
```

The HTML5 data- attributes are completely unrelated to jQuery's built-in .data() function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're wrong in general about `.data`: ["As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object."](http://api.jquery.com/data). But, mztwo is using 1.4.2 so you're right in this specific case.

Comment: @Elon.edu Webdev Bugger, I knew I was typing too slow :)

Comment: @mu is too short that's news to me thanks (mostly using Dojo).

Comment: @Josh I usually lose the speed battles, so I just got lucky this time... @mu that is really nifty. I had no idea jQuery did that, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thank you! And thanks to the other guy for pointing out that I'm using an old version of jQuery (I just discovered what jQuery was this Sunday and started using it) - this community is amazing in its speed and helpfulness.